# 256 grayscale Array for an Histogram VS C++ 2008

Tags: arrays, c++-cli, histogram

I'm trying to make a really simple "count" like array in Visual Studio C++ 2008.
The objective is to make a histogram (without displaying it) of a 256 bit grayscale image.

```
#pragma once
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System;

ref class Histograma
{
public:

    Histograma(void);
    Histograma(System::IO::FileStream^ archivo, List<Panel^>^ paneles);
    Array^ ejecutar();

private:
    Array ^resultado;
    Bitmap^ imagen;
};
```

and the implementation here

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Histograma.h"

Histograma::Histograma(void)
{
    resultado = Array::CreateInstance(int::typeid,256);
}

Histograma::Histograma(System::IO::FileStream^ archivo, List<Panel^> ^paneles)
{
    Histograma();
    imagen = gcnew Bitmap(archivo);
}

Array^ Histograma::ejecutar()
{
    System::Byte valor;
    for(int x=0; x < imagen->Width ; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y < imagen->Height ; y++)
        {
            valor = imagen->GetPixel(x,y).ToArgb();
            resultado[valor]++;
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

I'm getting a c2039 error: 'default' is not a memeber of 'System::Array'

Any ideas? This has to be something REALY simple that I'm doing bad, but I have no idea of what could it be.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Change the declaration to:

```
array<int> ^resultado;
```

And in the constructor:

```
resultado = gcnew array<int>(256);
```

**EDIT**:

You can also keep the original `System::Array` declaration and instead use this tedious syntax:

```
resultado->SetValue((int)(resultado->GetValue(valor)) + 1, valor);
```

Comment: Actually I tried this, and it's exactly the same. I finnaly found the problem though: I was calling the constructor with the parameters... which calls the constructor without parameters. I cannot call two constructors at the same time, it seems. Copy-pasting

`resultado = Array::CreateInstance(int::typeid,256);`

in the second constructor did the trick. Thanks!